# ExtJS: Master Detail grids using same store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid, extjs6-classic

I am new to ExtJS and am trying to find my way around. I am currently making a POC and am stuck at a point.

I am trying to create a master detail page with a Grid in master and a number of tabs in detail each with either a form or grid. Upon selecting a record from master grid on top, a detailed grid should be populated. The catch is, I want to use the same store for both the grids (master & detail) because I want to be able to make changes (add mater rows, add detail rows, remove rows etc) and then save those changes as a batch. Is it even possible? if yes, how should I achieve it? Do I have to use the same store or can I do batch editing some other way?

So far, I have tried to bind currently selected row to ViewModel (according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039955/extjs-two-way-binding-between-grid-form)) and tried the following to bind data to detailed grid

```
               bind: {
                    data: {
                        bindTo: '{selection.Details}',
                        deep: true
                    }
                }
```

Any help?

**Update 1:**

In my store, my data is in the following format (hence the same store for master-detail)

```
 items:
        [
            {
                Name: "ABC",
                Details:[
                         { 
                           detail1: 'asdf',
                           detail2:'qwerty'
                         }
                        ]
            }
        ]
```

**Update 2:**

Please see the following image. 
[image: What I want to achieve using extjs]

This is what I am trying to achieve. I want to use store for Master-Detail data. Is it possible? if yes, how?

**Update 3**

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17lf) to further clarify what I am asking for

Comment: There's an example of it here: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#binding-child-session, but I don't know what you mean by "I want to use the same store". If it's the same store, how is it a detail view?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli. I have updated my question.

Comment: you can pass the store between views inside the master view or get it from the StoreManager.

since you gave only a piece of code I can't recommend on the right way

Comment: @aviram83 I have updated my question. please take a look

Comment: can you create a small example in [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: @aviram83 I have created the fiddle. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your fiddle I have added a solution [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17pe)

If you look at sencha [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-data) you can see:

> The initial set of data to apply to the tpl to update the content area
>   of the Component.

so binding to data a dynamic value won't work.

Comment: If I add & remove records from detail grid, the change is not registered with the main store which means, syncing the main store doesn't fire Ajax requests. Any Idea? I tried marking the selected row as dirty but the payload to server contains the original detail records and not the updated ones

Comment: since you work on different store they are not sync, what you can try do to is when you add record (catch add/remove event) go to main store and add a record to the selected one.

Comment: Sure. Will try that. What I don't understand is that if I change something in the detail grid record, the change is made to the main store but if I add a detail record or remove one the change is not permanent. i.e. if I go to another record and come back I see my only the updated record and not the newly added or deleted record